# Changing SerializationMethod of a workflow

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

Update:

After some digging around, I have found a page for [Update-TypeData](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849908.aspx) that that has a method that states:

> -SerializationMethod
>   String: Serialize the type as a string. You can use the StringSerializationSource to specify a property of the type to use as the serialization result. Otherwise, the type is serialized by using the ToString method of the object.

This appears to be the problem I am having, however I can't run `Update-TypeData` in a workflow.

### Original Question

I have the following code:

```
workflow Deploy-Template
{
    Param
    (
        $Credentials, $resourcegroup, $count
    )
    $PSDisableSerializationPreference = $true
    $results = @() 

    $collection = (1..$count) 
    sequence
    {

        foreach -parallel ($item in $collection)
        {
            $subs = Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $Credentials

            $deploy = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ([guid]::NewGuid()).guid.tostring() `
                                                    -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup `
                                                    -TemplateFile "E:\tmp\storage.json"
            $obj= New-Object -type PSObject -Property  @{ 
            output = $deploy
            }
            $workflow:results += $obj
        }
        Write-Output $results 
    }
}

$value = Deploy-Template -Credentials $TenantObject.credential -resourcegroup $resourcegroup -count 1
```

When I run it and try to query the result I get:

```
PS > $value[0].output.Outputs.storageAccountName
Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.DeploymentVariable


PS > $value[0].output.Outputs.storageAccountName | gm 
TypeName: System.String
```

I've poked around and changed things and it seems that when run within a `Workflow` `$deploy` the DeploymentVariable is made a `string`.

If I just run:

```
$deploy = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ([guid]::NewGuid()).guid.tostring() `
                                        -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup `
                                        -TemplateFile "E:\tmp\storage.json"
```

I get:

```
PS > $deploy.Outputs.storageAccountName.Value 
y74ek7r67mq6c
```

Which is what I'm expecting. (there is no `value` property when it runs in a `workflow`)

I tried running it through `convertto-json` but it is doing the same.

Why can't I get my object out of my workflow?

**edited to add**

The relevant section of the `storage.json` file is

```
"outputs": {
    "storageAccountName": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[variables('storageAccount')]"
```

Run outside of the `workflow`

```
$deploy.Outputs.storageAccountName.GetType()
```

> IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
>   -------- -------- ----                                     --------
>   True     False    DeploymentVariable                       System.Object

While inside the `workflow` gives

```
$value[0].output.Outputs.storageAccountName.gettype()
```

> IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
>   -------- -------- ----                                     --------
>   True     True     String                                   System.Object

Running the code inline produces the same result

```
$deploy = InlineScript
{
  New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ([guid]::NewGuid()).guid.tostring() `
                                        -ResourceGroupName $Using:resourcegroup `
                                        -TemplateFile "E:\Git\Simplifed-Azure-Templates\storage.json"
}
```

Comment: The data which is shown as data type name should go inside "$()".

Comment: @SavindraSingh putting `output = $($deploy.outputs.storageAccountName)` gives the same result also (as well as adding .value on the end)

Comment: is the return type the same? e. g. `$value[0].output.GetType()` on the *workflow* and `$deploy.GetType()` if you just run the `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment` cmdlet? Also, do you have the Value property *within* your workspace?

Comment: @jisaak that's the part I don't understand, I have two different return types as you can see in the new part of the question. There is only a value property when it is run outside of the workflow. When it is inside the workspace it becomes a string and doesn't have a value property.

Answer (score 1):

[Objects in workflows are deserialized](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/automation-powershell-workflow/).

> The InlineScript activity is useful when you need to run one or more
>   commands as traditional PowerShell script instead of PowerShell
>   workflow. While commands in a workflow are sent to Windows Workflow
>   Foundation for processing, commands in an InlineScript block are
>   processed by Windows PowerShell.

Source is the above link.

You probably have to wrap your invoke within an `InlineScript`:

> You can return output from an InlineScript by assigning the output to a
>   variable.

Try this:

```
workflow Deploy-Template
{
    Param
    (
        $Credentials, $resourcegroup, $count
    )
    $PSDisableSerializationPreference = $true
    $results = @() 


    $collection = (1..$count) 
    sequence
    {

        foreach -parallel ($item in $collection)
        {
            $workflow:results += InlineScript {
                $subs = Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $Credentials

                $deploy = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ([guid]::NewGuid()).guid.tostring() `
                                                        -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup `
                                                        -TemplateFile "E:\tmp\storage.json"
                New-Object -type PSObject -Property  @{ 
                    output = $deploy
                }
            }
        }
        Write-Output $results 
    }
}

$value = Deploy-Template -Credentials $TenantObject.credential -resourcegroup $resourcegroup -count 1
```

Comment: `$PSDisableSerializationPreference = $true` *should* stop deserialization being the problem - and running in a workflow gives the same output (I will amend the question) - P.S. your code didn't actually have the inlinescript bit in ;)

Comment: Did you tried to access `$deploy.Outputs.storageAccountName.Value` within the `InlineScript` within the `workflow´?

Comment: I did, but because `$deploy.Outputs.storageAccountName` is still a string, there is no `value`

Comment: hmm, sorry. Then I have no more ideas.

Comment: not a problem, thanks for the thought! I think it might be a problem with the depth of the object,  but I've yet to prove that